# Optimizing 7z command line options for speed and compression ratio of large .bak files

Tags: command-line, compression, zip, 7-zip

I am currently dealing with a multitude of .bak files, each averaging around 300GB in size, and I need to compress them using the 7z command line. My primary objective is to strike a balance between the speed of compression and the compression ratio.

Currently, I am using the default 7z command line options, but I suspect there might be room for improvement. I am aware that options like `-m0=lzma2 -mx -mfb -md -ms -mmt` can be tuned to optimize the process, but I am unsure of the best settings for my particular use case.

So my question is, what are the best 7z command line options to compress large .bak files that will yield a reasonable balance between speed of compression and compression ratio? Also, if anyone could provide a brief explanation of how these parameters would affect the compression process, that would be extremely helpful.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: What is inside these files because compression strictly depend of the files entropy.

Comment: Also take a look in LZMA dictionary size, this can speedup the process, consuming more memory.

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself instead of relying on our untrustworthy opinions? Create two 10gb files out of one of the .bak files. Then extrapolate the results. I have no clue what a reasonable balance between speed of compression and compression ratio is for you because I don't even know if you own a datacenter or a 286.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html